# htaccess has broken my site

Tags: htaccess

I made a small addition to the htaccess file and it broke my site (I'm certain there were no errors, however). So I deleted what I added and 24 hours later the site is still broken.

I've disabled the htaccess file altogether.
replaced the wp-admin and wp-includes
moved all the themes off the server only leaving the default.
turned on debugging and no errors are produced

I only get the white screen of death.
I'm not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: Can you access wordpress admin section?

Comment: I cannot access any part of the site.

Comment: Are wp-admin, wp-includes and wp-content folders still on server? Is it possible for you to post website URL. If it's then enable debugging and post URL.

Comment: http://www.landlordservicing.com/

All three folders are on the server. I've enabled debug, debug_display and debug_logging. 

I'm not sure I understand your last sentence

Comment: Looks like website is working. Because HTML is there in source. rename plugin folder.

Comment: I think you tried to upload your website? It appears WordPress upgrade is incomplete. Check EDITs in my answer.

Comment: http://landlordservicing.com/

the site is loading with plenty of errors, and some of the stuff isn't working right, eg some of the plugins and the menus look wonky. 

but we're getting someplace, :)

Answer (score 1):

Enable debugging in wp-config.php and check for errors.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

If you see blank white screen then it means..

1. Either you renamed your theme folder name.
2. Some plugin is blocking access.

Enable debigging and post errors here.

**EDIT**

You will have to try uploading files manually.

Download no content WordPress from here.
https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.0-no-content.zip

Then delete wp-admin, wp-include and other php file except wp-config.php and wp-content folder.
And upload all files from wordpress-4.0-no-content.zip.
THis should work.

Also keep a backup before deleting any files on existing website.

Comment: I've already done that, and there are no errors produced on screen and no error log produced.

I also disabled the plugins folder.

Comment: Looks like you had it finxed now. :) Keep enabling WP_DEBUG and resolve all notices and errors. For each error and notice, search on Google for solution. You will probabli get a solution right away, if you do not get a soluton, ask here.